# Spam post flag declined

Tags: support

One of the post I flagged consisted only of spammy characters in a block, so I decided to flag it as a spam. But, when I looked at my flag reviews, it appeared as declined with the following post :

> **declined** - If the 'spam' flag option is no longer available, the post is already handled and doesn't need to be flagged for moderator
>   attention anymore.

Even though I'm pretty sure i used a "spam" flag for the post, and the post got deleted later on. In the end, the spam has been taken care of, but i was just wondering why i got a decline for that, and if it could be harmful if I want to flag other spam posts later on (i.e. will it affect my ability to report posts ?)

Comment: Spam flags should be used for unsolicited commercial messages, was the not in english text that or just something you didn't understand?

Comment: @RobertLongson: it was actual spam. However, by the time the OP got to the flag dialog the post had already been automatically deleted, because it had received 6 spam flags. At that point the flag dialog only gives you the *moderator attention* option.

Answer (score 6):

You didn't use a *spam* flag, you used a custom flag with the text *Not an answer, not in english (spam)*.

The moderator is trying to educate you about how to use flags. I wouldn't sweat one decline, take the feedback to heart and move on.

In this case the post had *already* been deleted by the time you opened the flag dialog (you loaded the page before it was deleted, clicked 'flag' after). It was deleted automatically because it had received 6 spam flags in quick succession.

Comment: I ment no harm ! I just wanted to be sure of the reason for this declined flag, as i though my flag was a spam flag. Thanks for the quick response anyway !

Comment: I know you meant to help, and that's great! But if we mark the flag as helpful, you'd probably not have received the feedback.